# Powershell V2 External MAML Help

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create an external MAML help file for a script Module. As a test I created a simple module called "ModTest" with 2 functions saved in a .psm1 file:

```
function Test-SqlScript2 
{
}
function Out-SqlScript2
{
}
```

I saved the module in my user Modules directory ~\Documents\Modules\ModTest
Next I created a subdirectory for a MAML file ~\Documents\Modules\ModTest\en-US
The MAML file I'm using for testing is available [here](http://cid-ea42395138308430.skydrive.live.com/embedicon.aspx/Public/Blog/ModTest.help.xml). I then started PowerShell and used Import-Module to import the module.

Unlike compiled cmdlets the placement of the file does not work by itself

So, next I tried adding the help link to the top of the script module, which also doesn't work:

```
<#
.ExternalHelp C:\Users\cmiller6\Documents\WindowsPowershell\Modules\ModTest\en-US\ModTest.help.xml 
#>


function Test-SqlScript2 
{
}
function Out-SqlScript2
{
```

Then I tried adding the help info to each function, which does work:

```
function Test-SqlScript2 
{
<#
.ExternalHelp C:\Users\cmiller6\Documents\WindowsPowershell\Modules\ModTest\en-US\ModTest.help.xml 
#>
}
function Out-SqlScript2
{
<#
.ExternalHelp C:\Users\cmiller6\Documents\WindowsPowershell\Modules\ModTest\en-US\ModTest.help.xml 
#>
```

**Two questions:**

1. Is it possible to create a script
   module level external MAML help OR
   do you need to specify the help link
   in each function?
2. Although the
       documentation claims and blog posts
       indicate that the language specific folder
       i.e. en-US will be automatically
       searched when specifying a path (~/ModTest\ModTest.help.xml) I
       could not get the MAML file to
       resolve unless I included the
       explicit path (~/ModTest/en-US/ModTest.help.xml). Is this a bug? See the following
       links for documentation on get-help and language specific
       folders:

[Writing Help for Windows PowerShell Modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878343(VS.85).aspx)
[PowerShell V2 External MAML Help](http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2008/12/24/powershell-v2-external-maml-help.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding #1, it appears to me that you have to specify the ExternalHelp comment tag for each command (script or function).  **Update:** I got confirmation from the PowerShell team that you have to specify the comment tag for each command.  I submitted a [suggestion on MSConnect](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=490788) that you can vote on if you would like to see this in a future version of PowerShell.

Regarding #2, it does work and from my testing you don't have to specify the full path (which is very nice).  Here are the contents of the module dir I created to test this:

```
~\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ModTest\ModTest.psm1
~\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ModTest\en-US\ModTest.psm1-Help.xml
~\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ModTest\fr-FR\ModTest.psm1-Help.xml
```

The contents of my ModTest.psm1 file is:

```
#  .ExternalHelp ModTest.psm1-Help.xml
function Add-BitsFile([object[]]$BitsJob, [string[]]$Destination, 
                      [string[]]$Source)
{
    Write-Host "Add-BitsFile"
}

#  .ExternalHelp ModTest.psm1-Help.xml
function Complete-BitsTransfer([object[]]$BitsJob)
{
    Write-Host "Complete-BitsTransfer"
}
```

The two ModTest.psm1-Help.xml files are just a copy of:

"$pshome\Modules\BitsTransfer\en-US\Microsoft.BackgroundIntelligentTransfer.Management.dll-Help.xml"

The biggest PITA in testing this out was to get a valid MAML file so I just copied a known working file.  :-)  BTW for the French version I just prefixed the synopsis with "Parlez vous" so I could test that it worked.

Next up, you need a quick way to change the thread currentUICulture to test the different, localized help files.  This is a function [Jeffrey Snover wrote some time ago](http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2006/04/25/583235.aspx).  I updated it to also change the CurrentUICulture:

```
function Using-Culture (
[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]$culture = `
    (throw "USAGE: Using-Culture -Culture culture -Script {scriptblock}"),
[ScriptBlock]$script= `
    (throw "USAGE: Using-Culture -Culture culture -Script {scriptblock}"))
{
    $OldCulture = [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
    $OldUICulture = [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture
    try {
        [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = $culture
        [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = $culture
        Invoke-Command $script
    }
    finally {
        [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = $OldCulture
        [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = $OldUICulture
    }    
}
```

Now let's test it:

```
PS> gmo|rmo
PS> ipmo ModTest
PS> Add-BitsFile -?

NAME
    Add-BitsFile

SYNOPSIS
    Adds one or more files to an existing Background Intelligent Transfer 
    Service (BITS) transfer job.

<snip>

PS> using-culture fr-FR {gmo|rmo; ipmo ModTest; Add-BitsFile -?}

NAME
    Add-BitsFile

SYNOPSIS
    Parlez vous adds one or more files to an existing Background 
    Intelligent Transfer Service (BITS) transfer job.
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll test the language specific folders further.

I have around 100 functions to create help for. I was hoping I could just reference the external help file once (module level help). At least I can point to single MAML file with. It might interesting to create a script to generate the MAML with stubs for the areas to fill in.

I also grabbed a working MAML from a couple of cmdlets I had written.

Comment: As a comment, it looks like PSv5 can use MAML help as long as it is in the same root folder as the `.psm1` file without any extra work as long as it is `<module>-help.xml`.  Tested by importing module without the file in place, calling get-help and getting the generic, pasting the file in and repeating, the MAML got pulled in automatically (and stays in as long as the module is loaded it seems).