# Syntax without path in own PowerShell manual

Tags: powershell, manual

I wrote a help header to my PowerShell script with respect to [this site](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff458353.aspx).
The script is stored in a directory which is added to the `env:path` variable.
When I call `help myscript` the help is returned, but the `SYNTAX` section shows the complete path. Is it possible to show only the script name? The name already shows the complete path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SYNTAX` is [autogenerated](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847834.aspx) for comment based help:

> AUTOGENERATED CONTENT
>
> The name, **syntax**, parameter list, parameter attribute table, common
>    parameters, and remarks are automatically generated by the Get-Help cmdlet.
>
> **...**
>
> Syntax:
>
> The Syntax section of the help topic is generated from the function
>    or script syntax. To add detail to the help topic syntax, such as
>    the .NET Framework type of a parameter, add the detail to the syntax.
>    If you do not specify a parameter type, the "Object" type is 
>    inserted as the default value.

Theoretically, one could override it using XML-based help, with `.EXTERNALHELP` keyword:

> .EXTERNALHELP
>
> Specifies an XML-based help file for the script or function.
>
> The ExternalHelp keyword is required when a function or script is
>   documented in XML files. Without this keyword, Get-Help cannot find
>   the XML-based help file for the function or script.
>
> The ExternalHelp keyword takes precedence over other comment-based 
>   help keywords. If ExternalHelp is present, Get-Help does not display
>   comment-based help, even if it cannot find a help topic that matches 
>   the value of the ExternalHelp keyword.

Example:

```
#  .ExternalHelp C:\MyScripts\Update-Month-Help.xml

param ([string]$InputPath, [string]$OutPutPath)
function Get-Data { }
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't make it work - PowerShell recognizes `ExternalHelp` keyword (results with/without it differ), but wouldn't load XML-based help.

Here is what I've tried:

`TestExtHelp.ps1`:

```
#.ExternalHelp TestExtHelp.xml
Param()
Write-Host 'Hello, World!'
```

`TestExtHelp.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<helpItems schema="maml">
<command:command xmlns:maml="http://schemas.microsoft.com/maml/2004/10" xmlns:command="http://schemas.microsoft.com/maml/dev/command/2004/10" xmlns:dev="http://schemas.microsoft.com/maml/dev/2004/10" xmlns:MSHelp="http://msdn.microsoft.com/mshelp">
    <command:syntax>
        <command:syntaxItem>
            <maml:name>Set-Test</maml:name>
            <command:parameter required="true" variableLength="false" globbing="false" pipelineInput="true (ByValue)" position="0">
                <maml:name>InputObject</maml:name>
                <maml:description>
                    <maml:para>output from get-test</maml:para>
                </maml:description>
                <command:parameterValue required="true" variableLength="false">Object</command:parameterValue>
            </command:parameter>
        </command:syntaxItem>
    </command:syntax>
</command:command>
</helpItems>
```

I've also tried making `TestExtHelp` a module and different combinations of paths, but no luck.

#### References

- [How to Add Syntax to a Cmdlet Help Topic](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb525442.aspx)
- [External MAML Help Files](http://sev17.com/2009/09/24/external-maml-help-files/)
- [PowerShell cmdlets and external help files](https://techsoda.wordpress.com/2010/09/29/powershell-cmdlets-and-external-help-files/)
- [Powershell V2 External MAML Help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432717/powershell-v2-external-maml-help)

Comment: I didn't encapsulate my script in a function. After that everything is fine. However, your comments and links are very useful!